# How to switch between blending modes in Adobe Illustrator with the keyboard?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts, blend-modes

In Photoshop you can select next or prev blending mode  with cursor up and down, but  **can't do the same in the Adobe Illustrator**. How to fix that? Maybe shortcuts or scripts can help...

[image]

Comment: In AI CC 2014 you need to select the object you want to apply blending mode changes to, then in the transpareny panel hover your curser of the blending mode and use your scroll wheel on your mouse.

Comment: This is why one always should consider the drawbacks of creating custom controllers, standard functionality like keyboard arrow stepping, mouse wheel compatibility etc. might be overseen.

Answer (score 7):

There's no default method.

However, if you choose Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts, then select the Tools option, you can configure your own shortcuts for blending modes.

[image: modes]

There is an issue where the blend mode won't move off of <kbd>Normal</kbd> with the <kbd>Next</kbd> and <kbd>Previous</kbd> commands. And it won't switch back to <kbd>Normal</kbd> when using <kbd>Previous</kbd> and <kbd>Next</kbd> commands. So you need to first move the mode off <kbd>Normal</kbd> then <kbd>Previous</kbd> and <kbd>Next</kbd> will work. Conversely, if you are on a different mode, you need to manually reset the mode to <kbd>Normal</kbd> because <kbd>Previous</kbd> and <kbd>Next</kbd> will not use that mode.

So, you need to assign a key to one of the modes, then the <kbd>Next</kbd> and <kbd>Previous</kbd> will work. For example, assign 4 to <kbd>Luminosity</kbd>, then 5 To <kbd>Next</kbd> and 6 to <kbd>Previous</kbd>. Select an object and tap the 4 key, then the 5 and 6 keys will work.

[image: assign]

Comment: To cycle through the modes, look for "Blend Mode - Next Mode" and "Blend Mode - Previous Mode" (they're cut off in the screenshot provided by Skaught). As far as I know there is no way to cycle through them with the arrow keys or mouse scroll as you would in Photoshop.

Comment: I tried to bind "Blend Mode - Next Mode" to a key combination - with no luck.

Comment: @yakunins see my updated answer....

Answer (score 3):

This shortcut works in Illustrator CC on Mac (and PC I'm told) so I hope it works for other versions too. Click on the drop down menu where it says Normal.With your mouse still over Normal just move it slightly and click and the drop down button should show a golden border around it. Once it shows that you can cycle through the blend modes with arrow keys, mouse, trackpad.   [image: Cycle through blend modes in Illustrator]

Answer (score 1):

Make the command work like PS to make it even easier.
'Shift +' for next blending mode and 'Shift -' for previous blending mode. (In CS5.1 for mac)
That way you don't even need a shortcut to a blending mode to begin with. Works like a charm.

Comment: I have just tried this in CS6 on Win8. It doesn't work. I binded "Blending mode - Next Mode" on (Shift + "+") and "Prev" on (Shift + "-"). No luck.